# Using Devexpress Ribbonform With Cefsharp Browser Resizes The Window To Smaller Size

Tags: .net, winforms, chromium, cefsharp, embedded-browser

I recently created a simple ribbonform app using devexpress winforms controls. Just see the images to understand what is happening. Everytime cef.initialize is called the window resizes and becomes smaller. Without the chromium browser added this is the screen :

[image: Main screen without any browser]

The moment I add a browser component to it, this is what it becomes :

[image: When I click Start button the window resizes and become smaller]

Both images might look same but second screen is 40% of first one.

The code is very simple :

```
Try
Dim cef1 As New ChromiumWebBrowser
cef1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
XtraTabPage2.Controls.Add(cef1)
cef1.LoadUrl("http://google.com")
Catch ex As Exception
MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

I even tried following settings but nothing happens :

```
Dim cefset As New CefSettings
cefset.DisableGpuAcceleration()
cefset.WindowlessRenderingEnabled = True
Cef.Initialize(cefset)
ChromiumWebBrowser1.LoadUrl("http://google.com")
```

I tried Googling but nothing comes up. Devexpress team says to ask Cefsharp dev team but I figured I will try first here. Any ideas on what might be happening?

Regards,

Comment: don't know why images are still not showing. Tried pasting and uploading, still nothing.

Comment: Make sure your app is DpiAware from the get-go

Comment: @jimi yup that did it. Setting DPIaware to monitor V2 did the job. Many thanks.

Comment: It depends on what .NET version you're targeting. You probably have a .NET Framework app, a .NET 5+ app would be DpiAware already. Read here: [High DPI support in Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/high-dpi-support-in-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) and check related SO answers here: [How to configure an app to run correctly on a machine with a high DPI setting (e.g. 150%)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13228185/7444103). If you're targeting .NET Framework 4.7.1+, use `app.config` to set a `PerMonitorV2` DpiAwareness mode

Comment: Also, try to design your app at 100% scale until you get the hang of it. VS issues a warning when you don't

Answer (score 0):

As recommended by Jimi in comment, I set my DPIaware to PerMonitor (V2) and it worked flawlessly.